# Subgradient of $\|AX\|_1$

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, subgradient

If $f(x) = \|AX\|_1$, where $\|.\|$ denotes the entrywise $\ell_1$-norm, what is the subgradient of $f(x)$?

Is there an expression similar to $A'A \ \partial \|X\|_1$? For example, $A = [1 \ 1;  1 \ 0; 0 \ 1]$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a chain rule for subgradients. I guess you are on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and there it holds, for example, for $f(x) = g(Ax)$, that
$$
\partial f(x) = A^T\partial g(Ax),
$$
see, e.g. Theorem 9.3 [here](https://maunamn.wordpress.com/9-the-subdifferential-chain-rule/).